# IE7 Issue with Lists

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer-7

I've got an issue with IE7. I've got a div titled "imageOptions" with an Unordered List inside it. In FireFox / IE8 etc. It shows the list as an inline 2 x 2 Unordered Lists. But in IE7 it shows it as a long list (4 Items). How do I achieve the IE8 / FireFox look in IE7? Here is my code (HTML First)

```
<div class="imageOptions">
  <?php do { ?>
  <ul>
    <li> 
     <a href="#" onclick="MM_swapImage('target','','propertyimages/<?php echo $row_select_property['image_url']; ?>',1)">
     <img src="thumbnail.php?image=propertyimages/<?php echo $row_select_property['image_url']; ?>" alt="Small Image 1" class="topImage" onclick="MM_setTextOfLayer('imageText','','<p><?php echo $row_select_property['image_desc']; ?></p>')" /></a>
    </li>
  <?php } while ($row_select_property = mysql_fetch_assoc($select_property));
</div>
```

CSS...

```
.imageOptions {
 clear: both;
 float: right;
 margin: 15px 75px 0;
 width: 185px;
}
.imageOptions ul {
 list-style: none;
 margin: 0;
 padding: 0;
}
.imageOptions li {
 float: left;
 padding: 5px;
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A quick guess: It may have to do with the missing closing tag for the list `</ul>` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you dont close off your `<ul>`

Comment: Thats a good spot, Added that to my page. It now displays inline. Should be able to go from here. The PHP While Loop over lapped the closing UL - It is further in my code, But had overwritten it.

Answer (score 1):

1) Use a CSS reset. The default margin and padding for lists on different browsers vary:

```
ul, li {
    margin:0;
    padding:0
}
```

2) Other than, `float:left` put all your styling on the `A` tag in the `LI` and use `display:block` on your A tag so you can make full use of margins and padding.

See my tutorial: [I love lists](http://preview.moveable.com/jm/ilovelists/).

Comment: Cheers for that. I've set an * for the page to margin: 0; and Padding: 0; - Tutorial is very useful for the future though!

Comment: * in CSS is very resource intensive. Avoid it if you can. The Yahoo CSS reset2 is what you should use: http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Answer (score 0):

You're missing a `</ul>` in the HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Move <ul> to before:

  `<?php do { ?>`